# storing matrices in golang in compressed binary format

Tags: python, numpy, go

I am exploring a comparison between `Go` and `Python`, particularly for mathematical computation. I noticed that `Go` has a matrix package [mat64](https://godoc.org/github.com/gonum/matrix/mat64).

1) I wanted to ask someone who uses both `Go` and `Python` if there are functions / tools comparable that are equivalent of `Numpy`'s [`savez_compressed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed) which stores data in a `npz` format (i.e. "compressed" binary, multiple matrices per file) for `Go`'s matrics?

2) Also, can Go's matrices handle string types like `Numpy` does?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the standard lib but you could combine two things to achieve this. Write the matrix as binary, compress the file. Alternatively I would suggest using Google protobuff because it probably will suit your needs and is becoming pretty common in my experience (in many languages, not just Go).

Comment: could also look into hdf5 formats, I know golang has a package to read/write them.

Comment: hdf5 is way too slow compared to npz and I mostly work with numpy (with some scipy).

Answer (score 2):

1) .npz is a numpy specific format. It is unlikely that Go itself would ever support this format in the standard library. I also don't know of any third party library that exists today, and (10 second) search didn't pop one up. If you need npz specifically, go with python + numpy.

If you just want something similar from Go, you can use any format. Binary formats include [golang binary](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) and [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/). Depending on what you're trying to do, you could even use a non-binary format like [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and just compress it on your own.

2) Go doesn't have built-in matrices. That library you found is third party and it only handles `float64`s.

However, if you just need to store strings in matrix (n-dimensional) format, you would use a n-dimensional slice. For 2-dimensional it looks like this: `var myStringMatrix [][]string`.

Comment: There is now a Go library for reading numpy .npy files:  https://github.com/kshedden/gonpy

Answer (score 1):

`npz` files are `zip` archives.  Archiving and compression (optional) are handled by the Python `zip` module.  The `npz` contains one `npy` file for each variable that you save. Any OS based archiving tool can decompress and extract the component `.npy` files.

So the remaining question is - can you simulate the `npy` format?  It isn't trivial, but also not difficult either.  It consists of a header block that contains shape, strides, dtype, and order information, followed by a data block, which is, effectively, a byte image of the data buffer of the array.

So the buffer information, and data are closely linked to the `numpy` array content.  And if the variable isn't a normal array, `save` uses the Python pickle mechanism.

For a start I'd suggest using the `csv` format.  It's not binary, and not fast, but everyone and his brother can generate and read it.  We constantly get SO questions about reading such files using `np.loadtxt` or `np.genfromtxt`.  Look at the code for `np.savetxt` to see how `numpy` produces such files.  It's pretty simple.

Another general purpose choice would be JSON using the `tolist` format of an array.  That comes to mind because `GO` is Google's home grown alternative to Python for web applications.  JSON is a cross language format based on simplified Javascript syntax.

Comment: fwiw, Go wasn't built as an alternative to Python directly, and not just for web applications. The project is to create a general systems language. Usually I'm replacing what I might have otherwise built with Java or C++. And perhaps python too.

Comment: I first read about it as an alternative language for the Google App Engine - some 4 years ago.  But I'm not surprised that Google would aiming for broader applications.

Comment: @hpaulj, I'm just exploring Go as it is in between C++ and Python and I'm facing speed issues with Python. I have designed and written binary file formats (some in Cython) that can be written/read from Python, including ones compressed by Python zip, I but haven't been able to come close to the speed of `.npz` or `.npy` files (even my own version of a faster min-Pandas written partially in Cython). Hence, my interest about Go. So far, trying to avoid migrating C++, but I'm generally coming to the conclusion that the only language with everything I need, and faster than Python is C++.

Comment: @uday While Go sounds fun, I am a bit skeptical about switching from Python to Go in order to improve write performance of a binary format. You can always make a C (or Cython) extension, as you have done,  called from Python. The speed will be mostly dependent on your implementation (use of compression, cache etc), and IO bound, not the language itself (i.e. Cython/C/C++/Fortran/Go, etc).    Also have you looked at the [`np.savez`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5d6a9f0030e8d1a63e43783c2b5b54cde93bc5d0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L603) implementation: it is pure Python and has good write speeds.

Comment: I'm a big fan of Go, but @rth is spot on. I recommend doing some measurements to see where your bottleneck is before spending a good amount of time trying to fix a problem that might not be. That being said if you just want to play with Go, do it :p